# Passport failing to serialize registered user on attempt to register again

Tags: express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm testing serialization on `local-signup` of an account that already exists but I am throwing an error (which doesn't seem right).  The error does not throw on original registration (only if I try to re-register).

```
//passport.js
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("serialize user", user);
     done(null, user.id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
  passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
  },
  function(req, email, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error
        if (err)
        return done(err);
        if (user) {
          console.log("user", user);
          return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
        } else {
          var newUser  = new User();
          newUser.local.email    = email;
          newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

          // save the user
          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err){
              console.log("error saving");
              throw err;
            }
            return done(null, newUser);
          });
        }

      });

    });

  }));

};
```

When I try to an account for the second time `Error: Failed to serialize user into session`

Edit:

```
// models/user.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// schema for user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  local : {
    email: String,
    password: String,
    displayName : String,
  },
});


userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

// expose user model to the app
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Edit #2:

```
// routes/routes.js
var User = require('../models/user');
module.exports = function(app, config, passport) {
  app.post('/signup', function(req,res, next){
    passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("err ", err);
          return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          res.status(500);
          return res.send('500');
        }
        res.status(200);
        return res.send('worked');
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
}
```

And here is roughly my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
require('./config/passport')(passport);
var app = express(); // sets up the server
app.use(session({ secret: 'damnfizzbuzzmyfoobar' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./routes/routes')(app, config, passport);
app.listen(3000);
```

I've done more digging and the problem probably is that when the email has been registered once and account creation is tried again, the user is being passed in as false to `passport.serializeUser()`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the else part in serializeUser, should work then.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
 });
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
});
```

**user model**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
        displayName : String
    }
});

userSchema.virtual('password')
.set(function(password) {
        this._password = password;
        this.salt = this.makeSalt();
        this.local.password = this.encryptPassword(password);
    })
.get(function() { return this._password });

var validatePresenceOf = function (value) {
   return value && value.length;
};


// methods ======================
userSchema.methods = {
  generateHash: function(password) {
      return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
  },
  validPassword: function(password) {
      return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
  },
  authenticate: function (plainText) {
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.local.password;
  },
  makeSalt: function () {
    return Math.round((new Date().valueOf() * Math.random())) + '';
  },
  encryptPassword: function (password) {
    if (!password) return '';
    var encrypred;
    try {
      encrypred = crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt).update(password).digest('hex');
      return encrypred;
    } catch (err) {
      return '';
    }
  } 
} 

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: I've attempted doing it like that but the error persists

Comment: Please update your post with UserModel, let me have a look into it.

Comment: Show me your github repo, or which every repository you are using. It is not a big problem, should not take much time to solve.

Comment: I've gone ahead and included the rest of my code that should relate to passport, unfortunately I am unable to share the repository